# Error importing android library into android project using rosjava.jar

Tags: ros, library, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There is a problem with importing
"import org.ros.rosjava.android.MessageCallable;"
"import org.ros.rosjava.android.views.RosTextView;"
which are part of the android library into the MainActivity.java inside the android project.

The project uses rosjava.jar which contains necessary java files to build; However, there is a difficulty with incorporating the android library into the project?

I am not that knowledgeable with using the android library together with rosjava. Can you advise on how to get this done?

Thank you!
Soe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10391/error-importing-android-library-into-android-project-using-rosjava.jar/) by [soetommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/442/soetommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2011-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, build the rosjava.jar by running ant dist in the rosjava directory. Currently, the directions to accomplish this are in flux, but it's something like this for the moment:

roscd rosjava
rosmake
ant dist

Then, you should be able to reference the Android library project by following the directions here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1